# 'Keeping up-to-date on' or 'Keeping up-to-date with'?

Tags: grammar

I recently replied to someone who was informing me about my application for something. I replied "Thank you for keeping me up-to-date **on** my application". Afterwards I wondered if I should have written "Thank you for keeping me up-to-date **with** my application".

Which is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a job applicant, and corresponding with someone at a company that is considering hiring you, neither *on* or *with* is correct, and the phrase *up-to-date* is a little too casual.  *Thank you for keeping me updated about the status of my application,* or *Thank you for updating me about the status of my application* would be more appropriate.  The first of my suggested rewordings would be appropriate if you have been updated more than once; the second, if only once.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You might use *on* for a topic ("keeping up to date on politics"), and *with* for a source of information ("keeping up to date with the television news") or an ongoing task ("keeping up to date with the housework"). For a particular matter, you'd keep up to date *about* it, which is what you want here.

You might also prefer *informed*. "Thank you for keeping me informed about the status of my application".

Answer (score -1):

In this example, the phrase up-to-date does not take hyphens because it does not refer to/precede a noun. "My up-to-date application" is correct, but "keeping me up-to-date on the status" is incorrect. No hyphens are used in the second example.

Comment: Not true.  Hyphens are perfectly acceptable in the second example.

Comment: Hyphens are used to form compound adjectives, that's why they're needed in `My up-to-date application`. As for `keeping me up to date / up-to-date on the status` it depends how we analyze it: as an adjective or as a static idiom/phrase.